# iptables rules on server break dynamic ssh port forwarding (SOCKS proxy) on local machine

Tags: ssh, iptables, socks-proxy

I use debian 9 on a rented VPS. On my laptop I use dynamic ssh port forwarding (using the SOCKS protocol) to tunnel the traffic of some applications. It all works fine but when I load the iptables rules on the server (the VPS) any application on my laptop that was using the local port forwarding stops working.

This is the command I use to forward local port 8080 of my laptop (debian 8) to my VPS:

```
ssh -D 8080 -N username@30.123.234.6
```

The above command starts returning errors like the following:

```
channel 7: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
channel 8: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
channel 9: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
etc...
```

Here is the output of iptables -L on the VPS. Can anyone see why these rules would cause this problem? Any idea much appreciated.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  google-public-dns-a.google.com  anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  resolver3.opendns.com  anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  resolver1.opendns.com  anywhere            
SYN_FLOOD_LOG_DROP  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
UDP_FLOOD_LOG_DROP  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ICMP_FLOOD_LOG_DROP  icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh     state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
SSH_LOG_DROP  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 4 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:xmpp-client state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
XMPP_LOG_DROP  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:xmpp-client state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 8 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
HTTP_LOG_DROP  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 8 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:xmpp-client
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost            anywhere             tcp dpt:5582

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain HTTP_LOG_DROP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning prefix "IPTables DROP:HTTPATTACK  "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ICMP_FLOOD_LOG_DROP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 1/sec burst 3
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning prefix "IPTables DROP:ICMPFLOOD  "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain SSH_LOG_DROP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning prefix "IPTables DROP:SSHATTACK  "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain SYN_FLOOD_LOG_DROP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 1/sec burst 3
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning prefix "IPTables DROP:SYNFLOOD  "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain UDP_FLOOD_LOG_DROP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 1 hit_count: 20 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning prefix "IPTables DROP:UDPFLOOD  "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain XMPP_LOG_DROP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning prefix "IPTables DROP:XMPPATTACK  "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is it logging? (Besides, just to clear up your terminology you don’t use a socks5 proxy on the vps, it is a dynamic ssh port forwarding which uses socks protocol on your local machine). Did you tried to make outgoing connections on that VPS? Might miss to accept established packets. I would first convert the drop policy into a reject/log rule then you see the missed packets.

Comment: Logging what was being dropped helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I took eckes' suggestion and tried to log what is DROPped by the INPUT policy. So I added the following rule as last in the INPUT chain:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables DROP: wrong drop " --log-level 4
```

This showed that a lot of stuff was actually being dropped, which probably should not. An example is this line from the log:

Dec 12 22:45:13 myservername kernel: [41817.875804] IPTables DROP: wrong drop IN=ens18 OUT= MAC=aa:43:9d:07:06:a7:00:1b:21:ad:d0:5d:08:00 SRC=149.56.134.238 DST=30.123.234.6 LEN=113 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=49 ID=471 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=6667 DPT=47054 WINDOW=227 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0

I was connected to IRC server 149.56.134.238 (cherryh.freenode.net) at the time of the test from my laptop using ssh dynamic port forwarding as described. I lost connection after iptables rules were loaded on the server (VPS).

So, I took eckes' advice again and tried to accept ESTABLISHED, RELATED packets by adding this line as the last rule of the chain (but before the debugging LOG rule mentioned above).

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --cstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Problem solved. I guess the lesson learned is that the first step with iptables problems is to check what is actually being dropped!